# Homogeneous or linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know what is different between homogeneous and linear differential equations.
For example:

a)$$(x\ln x)y'+y=3x^3$$

b)$$\sin (y)y^{(3)}+3y-e^x=0$$

c)$$\sin (x)y'+e^x=0$$

d)$$\sin(x)+ye^x=0$$

e)$$y^{(3)}+y^5=0$$

I think $a,b,$ and $c$ are linear because they are equations of both $x$ and $y$. But $d$ and $e$ are homogeneous. Actually, I don't know how you should think to about these problems.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: homogeneus equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation linear equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Linear differential equations don't have any products between $y$ or any of its derivatives. Basically, terms like $yy'$ or $y^5$ or $(y'')^2$ aren't allowed. They follow this pattern:
$$f_n(x)y^{(n)}+f_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+f_2(x)y''+f_1(x)y'+f_0(x)y=g(x)$$

Hint 2: Homogeneous differential equations don't have terms besides those which include $y$ or its derivatives. So no terms that are functions of only $x$ are allowed (including constants). Restricting to only first order terms (which is just for simplicity of writing this out. They exist at all orders) they are of the form:

$$f_1(x)[(y)^{i_1}]+f_2(x)[(y')^{i_2}]+f_3(x)[(y)^{i_3}(y')^{i_4}]=0$$

for constants $i$.

Hint 3: A differential equation can be both homogeneous and linear. Or a differential equation can be neither. A linear homogeneous equation is explicitly of the form:
$$f_n(x)y^{(n)}+f_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+f_2(x)y''+f_1(x)y'+f_0(x)y=0$$

---

Go through each of your differential equations and determine which are homogeneous. THEN go back through you list and determine which are linear. This way you don't confuse the two definitions. And since it can be neither, one, or both of these, it avoids drawing a connection between the two that doesn't exist.